# Access env variable with tox and Github Action

Tags: python, pytest, workflow, github-actions, tox

TL;DR: Empty env variables, but I don't know why.

I have a repo with a local `.env` file, and a Github Action workflow to launch some workflows when I push my commits to remote. I have also put the secrets of the env file as key-value pairs inside Settings / Environment secrets, one secret env for each line of my env file.

The problem is: when I run my tests locally, everything is fine and my test suite passes without any problem.
However, when I push my changes and the workflows start, they (coverage and test) fail because the secret isn't found - and it's mandatory for a test -, even if it should be found.

If it's important, I use tox to run my tests, and also passes the variables in the `env` block of the `tox` step. However, when the action is runned, the (snippet of) tox output is:

```
     def __init__(self):
        token = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_TOKEN", None)
        if not token:
>           raise ValueError("Missing token!")
E           ValueError: Missing token!
```

My `coverage.yml` looks like this (`tests.yml` is similiar regarding the env block):

```yaml
name: Coverage

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  coverage:
    name: Coverage
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
      - run: pip install tox
      - run: tox -e coverage
        env:
          TELEGRAM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
          TELEGRAM_CHAT_IDS: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_CHAT_IDS }}
```

EDIT:
I also found out that tox, by default, limits what's passed as env; however, even with [`passenv`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-passenv), I have always the same error.

EDIT 2:
Snippet of my `tox.ini`.

```
[testenv:coverage]
passenv = TELEGRAM_TOKEN TELEGRAM_CHAT_IDS

deps =
    -r requirements/base.txt
    -r requirements/test.txt

commands =
    coverage erase
    coverage run
    coverage html
    coverage xml
    coverage report -m
```

EDIT 3:
After tried with [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) and with some `echo` prints, it seems that the environment variables are empty, even if they are set. Somebody can tell me why?

Comment: can you show how and where you are invoking `passenv`

Comment: Updated my post; this is for the where. About the how, it should be automatic

Comment: `secrets` aren't exposed to pull requests by default (unless the PR comes from the repository itself) -- are these external pull requests? pushes?

Comment: @AnthonySottile nope, I read about this, but they were regular pushes made in main branch; btw I found the solution and already answered (cannot yet mark it as accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the environment was not set for the job ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment)), so even if the query was correct, the variable was always empty; in fact, when I uploaded the secret to the repository variables, it was detected.

Adding `environment: <name>` to the job solved the problem.